# What is the reason for the finally block to be lastly executed?

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

In Java, why does the "finally" block exist:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(...) {
    ...
} finally {
    // instructions lastly executed when the "try" block is quit
}
```

instead of a "firstly" block ?

```
try {
    ...
} firstly {
    // instructions firstly executed when the "try" block is quit
} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Whats a `firstly` block?

Comment: Please elaborate on your `firstly` block

Comment: The "firstly" block actually doesn't exist and my question is about the reason for it not to existing instead of the "finally" block.

Comment: Well you have to explain what a `firstly` block would be supposed to do if it would exist.

Comment: The "firstly" block would behave the exact same way as the "finally" block (when the "try" quits), but would be executed before the "catch" clauses (instead of after).

Answer (score 1):

This would be the same as

```
try {
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        // instructions firstly executed when the outer "try" block is quit
    }
} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

This isn't a common pattern, but if it was, it could be supported in a more idiomatic way.  Generally speaking `finally` is used to close of any resources which you no longer need and you are unlikely to want prevent access to those resources in your exception handling.

> The only difference is that the firstly block is executed before the catch clauses, instead of after as the finally block does. So for instance, it can properly close the resources, before the catch blocks (which could do a System.exit...).

I assume the closing of resources made more sense to place at the end of the block rather than in the middle.

Comment: You get a point. However, local variables in the try block cannot be used in the catch. If they are declared outside, they could be null (because an exception prevented them from being initialized before the catch). Moreover, the resource could launch an exception with the attempt to create one, and it couldn't be used in the catch. Btw: the finally would be the same as: `try { try {...} catch... } firstly {...}`.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont I think you have a point and +1'ed your question, but I think it's not as logical to arrange this way, though it could be because I am used the way it is. Possibly it works this way in some language they copied the feature from.

Comment: Thank you. I put a +1 to your answer because it brings some pieces of answer (although it doesn't solve it completely). I don't understand why I get negative points on this question.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont Why-are-things-the-way-they are questions often don't have a definitive answer and tend to get downvoted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

> In Java, why does the "finally" block exists:

A `finally` block exists so that it is always executed no matter where the `Exception` occurs ( either in `try` or in `catch` or doesn't occur at all ). `finally` is used to put code like closing file streams, clean-up code and the like...

If you don't like `finally`, then there is `try` with resources. You might want to use that.

> In Java, why does the "finally" block exists, instead of a "firstly" block ?

As the name suggests `finally` must contain the cleanup code, it cannot be placed before `catch` and be called some fancy `firstly`. The code in `finally` is executed even if an `Exception` is raised in `catch` block.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the point. The firstly block is executed even if an exception is raised in a catch clause. The firstly block can contain the cleanup code as well as the finally one.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont Then how is `finally` different from `firstly` at all?

Comment: The only difference is that the firstly block is executed before the catch clauses, instead of after as the finally block does. So for instance, it can properly close the resources, before the catch blocks (which could do a System.exit...).

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont Unfortunately, that's not what you do. You always handle an exception then, close your resources, not the other way around.